# send fake accelerometer or multitouch signal to an application on Android x86

Tags: sensors

I have this challenge:
I use proto.io to make demos of application I will develop, but this time I have to run it on a PC running Androidx86, connected to a touchscreen (no multitouch). Proto.io requires at startup to tap the screen with 3 fingers or to shake the device, obiouvsly I cannot do both as the PC don't have an accelerometer.
Is there any way to send a fake shake or multitouch to the app? I have already contacted the support team of proto.io, but they confirmed that right now there is no other way to start the application..
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, this can be done using app WIFI ADB - Debug Over Air installed in the device, after establishing a connection sending the command

> adb shell input keyevent 82

to shake the device.
Another solution I found was using app Tasker to send a shake.